# Fn key shows the desktop on my Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a MacBook Pro running OS X Lion 10.7 and somehow I changed the behavior for the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

Whenever pressed, it shows me the desktop.

It's driving me crazy because some applications require a combination of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key plus something else, so whenever I press the combination it still shows the desktop.

Comment: Have you installed any apps that change keyboard behavior?

Comment: Not that I can remember... I'm almost 99% sure that I have not, I usually don't install programs to tweak my system.

Answer (score 3):

OS X El Capitan 10.11

I found it, after years of searching.

System Preferences> Mission Control> Show desktop> Drop down menu change "Fn" to "-".

This has been the most annoying, niggling problem.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem. I got rid of this option by going to System Preferences > Misson Control. Where it says 'Show Desktop' it will say a key on the keyboard. Make sure it says  'fn' unless it does already. Then change it to '-' and this option will be gone :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't allow me to change it to a dash '-' my computer just beeps, I can add a different shortcut but the 'fn' key is still showing me the desktop!!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key was accidently set as a shortcut. In my experience with MacBooks, any "Key" related issues can be found here:

Apple Menu > System Prefrences... > Keyboard

[image]

Foe the Specific Shortcut you mentioned, I would check the "Show Desktop" in the "Keyboard Shortcuts" Menu.

[image]

Mine is set as <kbd>F11</kbd>. Make sure <kbd>Fn</kbd> does not appear there.

Comment: It seems impossible to even set `Fn` as a single shortcut key in OS X. Have you tried it?

Comment: Ha. Excellent point... I went through all this trouble but did not test the actual "fn" button. Sorry about that. I'll look a little further, but I'm currently stumped. Did you try "Restore Defaults"?

Comment: It's not me who had the problem :)

Comment: Another excellent point (clearly a newbie at superuser...). **MikeGA**, I would suggest "Restore Defaults" to see if that helps.

Comment: I have upgraded to Mountain Lion hoping it would restore it but I still have the same problem, at the screenshot above I can change the show desktop shortcut to something else but It doesn't remove "fn" behavior, it still shows me the desktop!! I'm very frustrated!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stumped. Have you tried posting this  same question on the ["apple" StackExchange site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)? There is likely more expertise there. Good luck and let me know if you found an answer!

Comment: Thank you Brad! I have not found a solution yet, I will try to post there and I'll post here if I find a solution.

Comment: Brad, sorry for stepping on your toes, but asking users to cross post is not encouraged. Ideally we'd like to have the same question only once across the network. hope you understand :) /cc @mik

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts too but I managed to find a fix for it, it's similar to bradpfeiffers solution above but resets all keyboard defaults at the same time.

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard 
In there I reset everything to default though I am not sure this is absolutely necessary. I also unticked everything to do with Mission Control.

Go to Mission Control Preferences
Untick all four options and change all four of the keyboard shortcuts to '-'

Then go back to Keyboard Preferences and reset defaults again.

Now my Fn key no longer shows the Desktop! I think it must have been a hangover from when I upgraded to 10.8 from 10.6.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy too. My solution was:

System Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard > Enable Sticky Keys

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was with the default setting which was changed without me noticing it - getting back to `Expanded Control Strip` did resolve the issue and the `ESC` key is back when I need it.

[my setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6D78.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to System preferences > Mission control.

There you can see show desktop shortcut set to Fn key. disable it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1146758)